# jQuery offset doesn't produce value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

before posting the whole code, i wanted to make sure I am not missing a simple issue here.

```
var dv = $(myElement);

var pos = dv.offset();
var width = dv.width();
var height = dv.height();

alert(pos);
alert(width);
alert(height);
```

here, width alerts fine, height alerts fine but offset alerts [object Object] (in firefox)

am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's correct: the `offset()` function returns an object containing two properties, `left` and `top`. (See [the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset)). "[object Object]" is how most objects are converted to strings.

I'd suggest you install Firebug to help you with debugging Javascript like this as it would give you much better information about the variables.

Answer (score 2):

Please also test with console.log() rather then alert()

Comment: using console.log() can break IE if forgotten

Comment: correct, you can do something like `if (window.console) console.log('hello world');
` or even shorter `window.console && console.log('hello world');
`

Answer (score 0):

:S I do apologise for consuming the valuable resources of this website by asking such a question which required client and server side validation, had to access a database and consumed internet bandwidth!!!! thats my anger to self! Think I should get some sleep now.. thanks guys...

Comment: haha don't sweat it - this page will be a saviour to a fellow sleep-deprived programmer one day...